# Messing around with batch

Tags: batch-file

Ive been messing around with batch and i wanted to try something i never have so i got to work on something small right now but something went wrong if anybody can help me, pls do.

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIX8v.jpg)

If u cant see it clear here is what they say

### BatchFile:

```
@echo off
set RunTimer=Call RunTimerCommand
set /p Testwadom=<Test.Wadom.txt
%TestWadom%
pause
```

### TextFile:

```
%RunTimer%
```

### ErrorMsg:

```
'%RunTimer%' is not recognized as internal or external command,

operable program or batch file
```

### Note: it should be making the code do call runtimercommand

Comment: Is this just a proof of concept because I can't think of any scenario where you would do that.

Comment: I have no idea what q proof concept means I don't use terms alot can u explain

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept. Note that in reality you'll never want to run user input like `%TestWadom%` as it'll be a major injection security issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is another layer of expansion, you can do that using `Call`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RunTimer=Call ThisTime"
Set /P "Testwadom="<"Test.Wadom.txt"
Call %TestWadom%
Pause
```

Alternatively you could use delayed expansion by setting up `Test.Wadom.txt` like this:

> ```bat
> !RunTimer!
> ```

and using:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RunTimer=Call ThisTime"
Set /P "Testwadom="<"Test.Wadom.txt"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%TestWadom%
EndLocal
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set RunTimer=Call RunTimerCommand
set /p Testwadom=<Test.Wadom.txt
call set TestWadom=%TestWadom%
%TestWadom%
pause
```

`call set` does another parse of the arguments so that `%RunTimer%`, as read from the file,
can be substituted with the value of `Call RunTimerCommand`.

In a similar manner. you can view the value of `%RunTimer%`, as read from the file, with `call echo`.

```
@echo off
set RunTimer=Call RunTimerCommand
set /p Testwadom=<Test.Wadom.txt
call echo(%TestWadom%
pause
```

The `(` after `echo` is like using `.` in `echo.` though less problematic.
It can help avoid the `echo is off` message if `Testwadom` is undefined.

Comment: kk I'll see if this will help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that batch only parsed your command once. It parsed `%TestWadom%` to `%RunTimer%`, but didn't parse `%RunTimer%` into `Call RunTimerCommand`. If you could explain to us why you need to parse a variable into another variable, we could figure out a solution.

Comment: it's kinda hard for me to understand u but to explain what I need, I'm trying to make custom commands that u type into a command file  then u have a batch that changes the commands to batch commands and runs those

Comment: I might understand u better now the reason I did it the way I did is because I'm gunna have more text in it and those each need to be converted but Im gunna have them more then once it's kinda hard to explain

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I'll try to figure this out

Comment: This is off the top of my head:

Comment: So, instead of having an actual command line, you would have a `set` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`
Is your friend for this use.

The below example Sets commands to an array, To assign them to Distinct names you'd need to modify the For loop or Process the Array a second time to reassign them to new variable names.

[Here's the example script with Ansi Character intact](https://pastebin.com/YQfenA9k):

```
@ECHO OFF

:start
Set Processed=0
Set "Val=0"
color 07
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:DefineArrays

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ Delims=#" %%c in ("target.bat") do (
    Set /a "Val+=1"
    SET "ScreenArray[!Val!]=%%c"
)

:UseObjects

FOR /L %%a in (1,1,10) DO !ScreenArray[%%a]! 2>nul

pause
exit
```

and example source: target.bat

```
#Mode 1000
#ECHO Testing Array
#TIMEOUT 1
#MODE con: cols=50 lines=30
#ECHO Definement Of Objects
#TIMEOUT 1
#MODE 1000
#ECHO For Use in Batch
#TIMEOUT 1
#CALL "%userprofile%\Desktop\target.bat"

Set "msg=[34mYour Message Here[0m"
@ECHO %msg%
TIMEOUT 1

:screen
@ECHO OFF
cls
color 02
mode con: cols=93 lines=13
ECHO ============================================================================================
ECHO = [33mLibrary of Objects as Commands, Functions and Programs for assignment to Array Elements[32m
ECHO =
ECHO = [36mTesting is Complete.[32m
ECHO =
ECHO = [36mYou now have the tools to use arrays Within Batch.[32m
ECHO =
ECHO = [36mdeveloped by: [37mT3RRY.[32m
ECHO =
ECHO ============================================================================================[0m
TIMEOUT 4
CLS
GOTO :EOF
```